# this error is giving no matter what i do Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation' I would like help to fix

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

This line of code is giving this error: Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'

```
// Moving Average function
ma(source, length, type) =>
    type == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, length) :
    type == "EMA" ? ta.ema(source, length) :
    type == "SMMA (RMA)" ? ta.rma(source, length) :
    type == "WMA" ? ta.wma(source, length) :
    type == "VWMA" ? ta.vwma(source, length) : na

maValue = na
if maTypeInput == "SMA"
    maValue := ma(rsiValue, maLengthInput, "SMA")
else if maTypeInput == "EMA"
    maValue := ma(rsiValue, maLengthInput, "EMA")
else if maTypeInput == "SMMA (RMA)"
    maValue := ma(rsiValue, maLengthInput, "SMMA (RMA)")
else if maTypeInput == "WMA"
    maValue := ma(rsiValue, maLengthInput, "WMA")
else if maTypeInput == "VWMA"
    maValue := ma(rsiValue, maLengthInput, "VWMA")

rsiMA = maValue
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any statement that is too long in Pine Script can be placed on more
> than one line. Syntactically, a statement must begin at the beginning
> of the line. If it wraps to the next line then the continuation of the
> statement must begin with one or several (**different from multiple of
> 4**) spaces.

[Source](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html#line-wrapping).

Below code will fix it.

```
ma(source, length, type) =>
    type == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, length) :
     type == "EMA" ? ta.ema(source, length) :
     type == "SMMA (RMA)" ? ta.rma(source, length) :
     type == "WMA" ? ta.wma(source, length) :
     type == "VWMA" ? ta.vwma(source, length) : na
```